# Do I Have To Restart The Entire Cell After Adding A Signer Cert To The CellDefaultTrustStore

Tags: ssl, websphere

I need to add a new signer cert to a bunch of WebSphere 8.5 instances in the CellDefaultTrustStore. After adding the cert do I need to restart the entire cell or just the application servers that are making outbound calls? Also, if I do have to restart "everything" does that include the node agents and dmgr?

Comment: Restarting only the application server making outbound calls should be enough.

Comment: Can you add some support for this suggestion?

Comment: Please be more specific. Which of the possibly many application servers are you referring to?